# How to store Degrees of directed graph into dictionary?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

While storing degrees against each node in directed graph. I'm facing below error.

```
degree = G.degree(G)
degree_values = dict(G.degree)
degree_values
```

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name. ie don't do `dict = ...`, or `G.degree` is a dict then `G.degree(G)` does not make sense

Comment: Can you add more relevant code please?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan in which context?

Comment: Have you re-defined `dict`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan Nopes.

Answer (score 1):

```
degrees_dict = {node:deg for (node, deg) in G.degree()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it with a key:

```
degree = G.degree(G)
degree_values = {"Key": degree}
```

If you're calling `dict()`, you have probably assigned it somewhere else:

```
# Don't do this
dict = ...
```

Don't re-define Python's built-in classes and/or functions

Comment: This will "work", but will just hide the actual issue with OP's code

Comment: Agreed, I'll append a warning